# How do I create this active_records query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have a user model and a story model.  Users have many stories.

I want to create a scope that returns the twenty-five users records for users who have created the most stories today, along with the amount of stories that they have created.

I know that there are people on SO that are great with active_records queries.  I also know that I am not one of those guys:-(.  Help would be greatly appreciated and readily accepted!

#UPDATE with the solution

I've been working with @MrYoshiji's suggestion, and here is what i came up with (note, I'm using this query in my active_admin dashboard):

```
    panel "Today's Top Posters" do
      time_range = Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day
      table_for User.joins(:stories)
          .select('users.username, count(stories.*) as story_count')
          .group('users.id')
          .where(:stories => {:created_at => time_range})
          .order('story_count DESC')
          .limit(25) do
              column :username
              column "story_count"
      end
  end
```

And low and behold, it works!!!!

Note, when I tried a simplified version of MrYoshiji's suggestion:

```
User.includes(:stories)
    .select('users.username, count(stories.*) as story_count')
    .order('story_count DESC') #with or without the group statement
    .limit(25)
```

I got the following error:

```
    >   User.includes(:stories).select('users.username, count(stories.*) as story_count').order('story_count DESC').limit(25)
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "users".id, story_count AS alias_0 FROM "users" LEFT OUTER JOIN "stories" ON "stories"."user_id" = "users"."id" ORDER BY story_count DESC LIMIT 25
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  column "story_count" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "users".id, story_count AS alias_0 FROM "us...
```

It seems like includes don't like any aliasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using .includes, as suggested by MrYshiji, did not work due to aliasing problems (see the original question for more info on this).  Instead, I used .joins as follows to get the query results that I wanted (note, this query is inside my active_admin dashboard):

```
panel "Today's Top Posters" do
  time_range = Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day
  table_for User.joins(:stories)
      .select('users.username, count(stories.*) as story_count')
      .group('users.id')
      .where(:stories => {:created_at => time_range})
      .order('story_count DESC')
      .limit(25) do
          column :username
          column "story_count"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this right now, running under Windows... Can you try it?

```
User.includes(:stories)
     .select('users.*, count(stories.*) as story_count')
     .group('users.id')
     .order('story_count DESC')
     .where('stories.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', Date.today.beginning_of_day, Day.today.end_of_day)
     .limit(25)
```

Comment: We clearly see that the SQL request does not have the 'count' part. I'm gonna update my answer, hopefully it'll work now!